# Как значение из инпутов перевести в переменную файла js?

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть гугл расширение, в popup.html есть три инпута и кнопка

```
   <p class="in">Name</p>
   <input type="text" id="name">

   <p class="in">Last name</p>
   <input type="text" id="lastname">

   <p class="in">Link</p>
   <input type="text" id="link">

   <button type="submit" id="save">Save</button>
```

В первые два поля я ввожу данные, а в третий ссылку на сайт, при нажатии кнопки мне нужно сохранить значения в переменные, открыть ссылку и запустить js код с этими переменными. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не понятно, какую ссылку Вы хотите открыть? внешнюю? JS/jQuery не могут открывать кроссдоменные ссылки (CORS)

Comment: если все таки нельзя и очень хочется , посмотрите в сторону axios

Comment: @ktscript, спасибо за информацию, а как все таки перевести данные в переменные и запустить с ними код по клику по кнопке?

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос только в инпутах, можно например так:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST)) : ?>

<script>
   let name = <?= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "", 
       lastname = <?= isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : "", 
       link = <?= isset($_POST['link']) ? $_POST['link'] : ""; 
   ...
</script>

<? endif; ?>

<form action="PATH_TO_THIS_PHP_FILE" method="post">
   <label>Name
   <input type="text" name="name"></label>

   <label>Last name
   <input type="text" name="lastname">

   <label>Link
   <input type="text" name="link"></label>

   <button type="submit" id="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

массивы можно через JSON передавать.

Comment: а можно это сделать без php?

Comment: конечно. Вам бы лучше почитать документацию, чтобы было больше понимания. Если не менять пример выше, обратиться можно так, подключив библиотеку jQuery: $('#save').on('click', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); let name = $('input[name="name"]').val(); ... });

Comment: только запрос на сторонний сайт через JS, как я писал выше Вы не сделаете.